# Use of pointer to uint_8

Tags: c++, types

In the cryptographic library Botan we have the `class Cipher_Mode`
and its method `void set_key(const uint8_t *key, size_t length)` that set the symmetric key to be used.

So here `key` is a pointer to an unsigned int of fixed width 8. However the key is supposed to be a little bigger. In the botan [documentation](https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/cipher_modes.html#cipher-modes)  `key`is set as a `const std::vector<uint8_t>`.

If I understand well, we ask for a pointer to a key, and its length  to get the positions of the first bit of the key and the length gives the information on where the key storage is stopped.

Is my interpretation right ?

Comment: The key is a sequence of bytes. `uint8_t *, size` pair and `std::vector<uint8_t>` are merely two ways to represent a sequence of bytes.

Comment: The example in that article doesn't match the documentation. For the example to compile, there should be an overload of `set_key` taking a vector, perhaps in addition to the one taking pointer and length.

Comment: Looks like equivalent logic, but implemented in C and then C++.

Comment: `uint8_t` is type byte. The pointer points to the first byte of the key - the remaining `length - 1` bytes follow.